# Simple ng-show isn't working

Tags: angularjs

My simple ng-show isn't working div should be hide when other values are selected.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-radio-input-directive-production</title>


  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.10/angular.min.js"></script>



</head>
<body ng-app="">
   <script>
   function Ctrl($scope) {
     $scope.color = 'blue';
     $scope.specialValue = {
       "id": "12345",
       "value": "green"
     };
   }
 </script>
 <form name="myForm" ng-controller="Ctrl">
   <input type="radio" ng-model="color" value="red">  Red <br/>
   <input type="radio" ng-model="color" ng-value="specialValue"> Green <br/>
   <input type="radio" ng-model="color" value="blue"> Blue <br/>
   <tt>color = {{color | json}}</tt><br/>
  </form>
  Note that `ng-value="specialValue"` sets radio item's value to be the value of `$scope.specialValue`.
  <div ng-show="color==blue">some test</div>
</body>
</html>
```

here is [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/eO8NtoeN7oMycNTMMjyL?p=preview)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your ng-show is outside the scope of your controller.

Do this:

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <form name="myForm">
    <input type="radio" ng-model="color" value="red">  Red <br/>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="color" ng-value="specialValue"> Green <br/>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="color" value="blue"> Blue <br/>
    <tt>color = {{color | json}}</tt><br/>
  </form>
  <div ng-show="color=='blue'">some test</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks like it's too late to post my answer, but here's a Plunkr of the above: http://plnkr.co/edit/6OlKKgbBe190I2clkqT2

Answer (score 1):

You have to write it like this since blue is a string:

```
ng-show="color == 'blue'"
```

Answer (score -1):

your ng-show is outside the controller scope and try to use  'body ngApp=""'instead of 'body ng-app=""'